# Bind HTML table TH dynamically using View Model Failed

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor, viewmodel, asp.net-core-3.1

I am trying to bind the HTML table using the View Model of type Object on the Razor Page. Code is as below :

> index.cshtml.cs

```
[BindProperty]
public List<object> TableData { get; set; }

public class Cainfo
{
   public string Ca_id { get; set; }
   public object Nca { get; set; }
}

public async Task<IActionResult> OnGetAsync()
{
   List<object> tablerows = GetTableRows(tabledata);
   TableData = tablerows;
}

public List<object> GetTableRows(GetTableRowsResponse getTableRowsResponse)
{
       List<object> tableRows = new List<object>();
            
       var tables = getTableRowsResponse.rows;
       foreach (var table in tables)
       {
             var tab = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(table);
             var row = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Cainfo>(tab);
             tableRows.Add(row);
       }
       return tableRows;
}
```

> index.cshtml

```
<table class="resultTable">
   <thead class="grid-header">                                                 
      <tr>                             
        @foreach (var property in @Model.TableData.GetType().GetGenericArguments()[0].GetProperties())
        {
          <th class="col-lg-1">@property.Name</th>
        }
       </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody class="grid-body">
       @if (@Model.TableData != null)
       {
           @if ((@Model.TableData.Count != 0))
           {
              @foreach (var row in Model.TableData)
              {
                 <tr>
                  @foreach (var property in @row.GetType().GetProperties())
                  {
                     <td class="col-lg-1">@property.GetValue(@row)</td>
                  }
                 </tr>
              }
           }
       }                                
     </tbody>
</table>
```

`var tables = getTableRowsResponse.rows;` return the JSON data. Problem is that table `<th>` is not getting bind. `@Model.TableData.GetType().GetGenericArguments()[0].GetProperties()` is getting empty. `<td>` is getting bind as expected. Maybe I am doing a mistake somewhere, I am new to the asp .net core. Now, I am using the Model `Cainfo` but in future, I need to set different models according to data and bind the same table. That's why I am giving View Model type as Object. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would not use reflection like this when you can design common models for the view. That's the art of designing which makes things easier. However here assume that you want to stick with that solution anyway, I'll show where it's wrong and how to fix it and how it's limited.

First this `Model.TableData.GetType().GetGenericArguments()[0]` will return `Type` of `object`. And that `Type` of course contains no properties. That's why you get no `<th>` rendered. The generic argument type exactly reflects what's declared for `Model.TableData` which is a `List<object>`.

Now to fix it, assume that all the items in the `List<object>` are of the same type, you can get the first item's `Type`, like this:

```
@foreach (var property in @Model.TableData?.FirstOrDefault()
                                          ?.GetType()?.GetProperties() 
                                          ?? Enumerable.Empty<PropertyInfo>())
{
   <th class="col-lg-1">@property.Name</th>
}
```

That has a limit in case the `Model.TableData` contains no item. No `<th>` will be rendered. If that's acceptable (instead of rendering an empty table with headers, you will render nothing or just some message) then just go that way. Otherwise, you need to provide a `Type` for the element/row's `Type`via your model, such as via a property like `Model.RowType`. Then you can use that instead of this:

```
 Model.TableData?.FirstOrDefault()?.GetType()
```

The remaining code is just the same.

Comment: For trying the first solution its giving error:  ```The type or namespace name PropertyInfo could not be found```

Comment: @Varsh you need to add `using System.Reflection;` because `PropertyInfo` is defined in that namespace.

Comment: I added this namespace in ```.cshtml.cs``` file but still, it is giving the same error.

Comment: @Varsh in the view file, you will write it as `@using System.Reflection` right at the beginning of the file. It's impossible for that such error after you include that `using` directive.

Comment: if you have difficulty adding the using namespace directive, you can write the type directly like this `System.Reflection.PropertyInfo`

Comment: Yes, this error is gone now. Thank you! I will test the code and let you know if any problem.